# DRF SocialLoginView callback_url is not redirecting on AppleLogin

Tags: python, django-allauth, django-rest-auth, apple-login

Trying to implement apple login in django rest allauth.
`/user/apple/` creates the account. And callback_url is set to `/user/apple/login/callback/`

When I hit callback_url from POSTMAN, it redirects. But the endpoint `/user/apple/` does not call the callback_url.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
...
    path("user/apple/", AppleLogin.as_view(), name="apple-login"),
    path('user/apple/login/callback/', apple_callback, name="apple_callback"),
...
]
```

views.py

```
from rest_auth.registration.views import SocialLoginView
...
class AppleLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = AppleOAuth2Adapter
    # also tried this way
    # callback_url = '<doamin>/user/apple/login/callback/'
    client_class = AppleOAuth2Client
    serializer_class = CustomAppleSocialLoginSerializer

    @property
    def callback_url(self):
        return self.request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('apple_callback'))


def apple_callback(request):
    return redirect('<domain>/editprofile')
...
```

serializers.py is working with `CustomAppleSocialLoginSerializer` and the account is also being created in the database.

What can be going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The redirectlink is without the `/` at the end. So `# callback_url = '<doamin>/user/apple/login/callback'`